# Why is the value of id getting randomized?

Tags: php, mysql

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SomuFinance - Personal Finance Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexStyle.css">
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #addItemContainer {
            background-color: rgba(204,207,232,1);
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flag=0;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="list" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <div id="container">
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="edit" id="edit" value="Edit" />
            <input type="button" class="button" name="delete" value="Delete" />
            <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action">
            <table id="listDB">
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Category ID</th>
                    <th>Shop</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Price Based On</th>
                    <th>MRP</th>
                    <th>Seller's Price</th>
                    <th>Last Updated On</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $dbc =  mysqli_connect('localhost','root','atlantis2016','itemDB')
                                or die("Error Connecting to Database");

                    if(isset($_POST['confirmDelete']))
                    {
                        if($_POST['action']=='confirmDelete')
                        {
                            foreach ($_POST['selected'] as $delete_id) 
                            {
                                $query = "DELETE FROM grocery WHERE id = $delete_id";
                                mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                                    or die('Error querying database.');
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM grocery";
                    $result1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1)
                                or die("Error Querying Database");

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
                    {
                        $category = $row['category'];
                        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM grocery WHERE category='$category' ORDER BY item ASC";
                        $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2)
                                or die("Error Querying Database");

                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td class="catHead" colspan=11>'.$category.'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                        $catCount=1;

                        while($inRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                        {
                            $id = $inRow['id'];
                            $shop = $inRow['shop'];
                            $item = $inRow['item'];
                            $qnty = $inRow['quantity'];
                            $unit = $inRow['unit'];
                            $price_based_on = $inRow['price_based_on'];
                            $mrp = $inRow['MRP'];
                            $sellers_price = $inRow['sellers_price'];
                            $last_updated_on = $inRow['last_updated_on'];

                            echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" id="selected" value="' . $id . '" name="selected[]" /></td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$id.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$catCount.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$shop.'</td>';
                                echo '<td class="leftAligned">'.$item.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$qnty.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$unit.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$price_based_on.'</td>';
                                echo '<td class="pri">₹'.$mrp.'</td>';
                                echo '<td class="pri">₹'.$sellers_price.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$last_updated_on.'</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';

                            $catCount++;
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="dialogBG">
            <div id="deleteConfirmDialog" class="dialog">
                <div class="closeDialog"></div>
                <p>Sure you want to delete the selected Data?</p>
                <input type="submit" id="confirmDelete" class="dialogButton" name="confirmDelete" value="Delete" />
                <input type="button" id="cancelDelete" class="dialogButton cancelButton" name="cancelDelete" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="dialogBG">
        <div id="addItemContainer" class="dialog">
            <div class="closeDialog"></div>
            <h1>Edit Item</h1>
            <form id="data" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['action']))
                    {
                        if($_POST['action']=='edit')
                        {
                            echo '<script>flag=1;</script>';
                            foreach ($_POST['selected'] as $edit_id) 
                            {
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM grocery WHERE id = $edit_id";
                                $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                                            or die('Error querying database.');
                                break;
                            }

                            $inRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

                            $id = $inRow['id'];
                            $shop = $inRow['shop'];
                            $category = $inRow['category'];
                            $item = $inRow['item'];
                            $qnty = $inRow['quantity'];
                            $unit = $inRow['unit'];
                            $price_based_on = $inRow['price_based_on'];
                            $mrp = $inRow['MRP'];
                            $sellers_price = $inRow['sellers_price'];
                            $last_updated_on = $inRow['last_updated_on'];

                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <div class="leftAligned">
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="shop">ID : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" required disabled>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="shop">Shop : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="shop" name="shop" value="<?php echo $shop; ?>" required>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="category">Category : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="category" name="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" required>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="item">Item : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="item" name="item" value="<?php echo $item; ?>" required>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="qnty">Quantity : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="qnty" name="qnty" value="<?php echo $qnty; ?>" required>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="unit">Unit : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="unit" name="unit" value="<?php echo $unit; ?>" required>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="price_based_on">Price based on : </label>
                        <select name="price_based_on" id="price_based_on">
                            <option value="kilos">Kilos</option>
                            <option value="packet">Packet</option>
                            <option value="bottle">Bottle</option>
                            <option value="box">Box</option>
                            <option value="piece">Piece</option>
                        </select>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="mrp">MRP (₹) : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="mrp" name="mrp" value="<?php echo $mrp; ?>" required>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="sellers_price">Seller's Price (₹) : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="sellers_price" value="<?php echo $sellers_price; ?>" name="sellers_price" required>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="inp">
                        <label for="last_updated_on">Last Updated on : </label>
                        <input type="date" id="last_updated_on" name="last_updated_on" value="<?php echo $last_updated_on; ?>" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="inp">
                    <input id="insertButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert">
                </div>
                <div id="message">
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {

                            echo "<script> alert('$id'); </script>";
                            $shop = $_POST['shop'];
                            $category = $_POST['category'];
                            $item = $_POST['item'];
                            $qnty = $_POST['qnty'];
                            $unit = $_POST['unit'];
                            $price_based_on = $_POST['price_based_on'];
                            $mrp = $_POST['mrp'];
                            $sellers_price = $_POST['sellers_price'];
                            $last_updated_on = $_POST['last_updated_on'];
                            $result=null;

                            $query = "UPDATE grocery SET shop='$shop', category='$category', item='$item', quantity='$qnty', unit='$unit', price_based_on='$price_based_on', mrp='$mrp', sellers_price='$sellers_price', last_updated_on='$last_updated_on' WHERE id='$id'";

                            if(!empty($shop)&&!empty($category)&&!empty($item)&&is_numeric($qnty)&&!empty($unit)&&is_numeric($mrp)&&is_numeric($sellers_price)&&!empty($last_updated_on))
                            {
                                $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                                                    or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
                            }

                            if($result)
                            {
                                echo '<span class="success">Item Edited Successfully!</span>';  
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '<span class="failure">Failed to insert Item.</span>';
                            }
                            //header("Refresh:2");
                        }
                    ?>
                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){

                        $( "#data" ).validate({
                          rules: {
                            qnty: {
                              number: true
                            },
                            mrp: {
                              number: true
                            },
                            sellers_price: {
                              number: true
                            }
                          },
                          messages: {
                            qnty : {
                                number: '<br> <span class="failure err">Enter a valid quantity</span>'
                            },
                            mrp : {
                                number: '<br> <span class="failure err">Enter a valid MRP</span>'
                            },
                            sellers_price : {
                                number: '<br> <span class="failure err">Enter a valid Price</span>'
                            },
                          }
                        });
                    });
                    </script>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.button').click(function(event){
                if($(this).val()=="Delete")
                {
                    $("#deleteConfirmDialog").show(200).parent(".dialogBG").fadeIn(200);
                    $("#action").val('confirmDelete');
                }
                else if($(this).val()=="Edit")
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#action").val('edit');
                    $("#list").submit();
                }
            });

            if(flag===1)
            {
                console.log("This shouldn't be there if the page reloads!");
                $("#addItemContainer").show(200).parent(".dialogBG").fadeIn(200);
            }

            $('#confirmDelete').click(function(){
                $(".closeDialog").trigger("click");
            });
            $('#cancelDelete').click(function(){
                $("input:checkbox[name='selected[]']").prop('checked', false);
            });
            $(".closeDialog").click(function (e){
                $(this).parent(".dialog").hide('200').parent(".dialogBG").fadeOut('200');
            });
            $(".cancelButton").click(function (e){
                $(this).parent(".dialog").hide('200').parent(".dialogBG").fadeOut('200');
            });
        });
    </script>

    <?php
        mysqli_close($dbc);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that I obtain the id of the first selected element by using the lines:

```
foreach ($_POST['selected'] as $edit_id) 
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM grocery WHERE id = $edit_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                or die('Error querying database.');
    break;
}

$inRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$id = $inRow['id'];
```

Now, I use the `id`(which is exactly the same as `edit_id`) thus obtained to access the record in the DB, and show it in the popup.

```
<div class="leftAligned">
      <div class="inp">
            <label for="shop">ID : </label>
            <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" required disabled>
      </div> <br>
      <div class="inp">
            <label for="shop">Shop : </label>
            <input type="text" id="shop" name="shop" value="<?php echo $shop; ?>" required>
      </div> <br>
      <div class="inp">
            <label for="category">Category : </label>
            <input type="text" id="category" name="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" required>
      </div> <br>
      <div class="inp">
          <label for="item">Item : </label>
          <input type="text" id="item" name="item" value="<?php echo $item; ?>" required>
      </div> <br>
      <div class="inp">
          <label for="qnty">Quantity : </label>
          <input type="text" id="qnty" name="qnty" value="<?php echo $qnty; ?>" required>
      </div> <br>
      <div class="inp">
          <label for="unit">Unit : </label>
          <input type="text" id="unit" name="unit" value="<?php echo $unit; ?>" required>
      </div> <br>
      <div class="inp">
          <label for="price_based_on">Price based on : </label>
          <select name="price_based_on" id="price_based_on">
              <option value="kilos">Kilos</option>
              <option value="packet">Packet</option>
              <option value="bottle">Bottle</option>
              <option value="box">Box</option>
              <option value="piece">Piece</option>
          </select>
      </div> <br>
      <div class="inp">
          <label for="mrp">MRP (₹) : </label>
          <input type="text" id="mrp" name="mrp" value="<?php echo $mrp; ?>" required>
      </div> <br>
      <div class="inp">
          <label for="sellers_price">Seller's Price (₹) : </label>
          <input type="text" id="sellers_price" value="<?php echo $sellers_price; ?>" name="sellers_price" required>
      </div> <br>
      <div class="inp">
          <label for="last_updated_on">Last Updated on : </label>
          <input type="date" id="last_updated_on" name="last_updated_on" value="<?php echo $last_updated_on; ?>" required>
      </div>
</div>
```

The ID and all the relevant details thus far are exactly as they should be.

However, further down, when I try to use the ID to update the record, using the statement

```
UPDATE grocery SET shop='$shop', category='$category', item='$item', 
                    quantity='$qnty', unit='$unit', price_based_on='$price_based_on', 
                    mrp='$mrp', sellers_price='$sellers_price', 
                    last_updated_on='$last_updated_on' 
WHERE id='$id'
```

somehow the id has changed to the last value of id in the table. So, instead of updating the table's correct record with the updated values, since the id "magically" changes at this point (after the sumbit button has been pressed), the last value of the id appears. I want the id to stay the same as the original id.

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: This is a lot of code, and I'm not exactly sure what you're asking either. You say you get an error, but we have no idea what that is unless you tell us.

Comment: @Qirel tried to explain better. Am i making sense now?

Comment: If the value of `$id` is changing between one part of the code and the other, and you can show that by printing it out at both places, then we would probably need to see what code goes between those two places rather than just saying "futher down..."

Comment: is the id `AUTO_INCREMENT ` id if so I would use a different value to up date products `$query = "SELECT * FROM grocery WHERE item = $edit_item";`

Comment: @moopet For example, if the checkbox related to id=2 is selected, the correct product is shown in the consequent insertion form. Now, when I edit some value (NOT the ID), and click the sumbit button, suddenly in the next part of the code where I alert the value of id, it changes to something like 120! I don't get why this happens.